# How to make ActiveStorage work on two apps sharing the same DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I have two Rails apps on Heroku sharing the same DB, let's call them App1 and App2.

On App1 I use ActiveStorage to handle images (stored on S3).

On App2, I have this for the model

```rb
class ReferralHub < ApplicationRecord

  self.table_name = "referral_hubs"

  has_one_attached :logo
end
```

and this for the view:

```html
<%= image_tag(url_for(@hub.logo") %>
```

For some reasons, images on App2 are not displayed.

I've also noticed that the URL of the image in App2 is slightly different than the URL of the image in App1.

Do I have to do anything special to make images in App2 show up?

Thanks

Comment: Are the two apps the same Rails / Ruby version / Gem version? You said that the url of the images is slightly different between images, in which way exactly?

Comment: Can you elaborate about why it's important to share the database? Is it to share data between the apps or some other reason? Maybe there's a better way to approach this?

Comment: @Damien-Layershift is to share data between two apps. This thing can't be changed.

Comment: @cesartalves same Ruby version (2.5) but different Rails version (App1 is on Rails 5.2, App2 is on Rails 6). Can that be the difference?

Comment: @cesartalves They are different in that this is the URL of the image on App1:
```/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBVZz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--2ee68fb188c120f07c9e7764aa663a96128310ac/logos1912230-01.jpg```

and this is the URL in App2: 
```/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBVZz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--ac62412c6a44bcaa80fee8bb227c3cddc92e5c0b/logos1912230-01.jpg```

You can see the second part, after the --- is different.

Comment: I see. Do you notice that a small segment of the url is different? ActiveStorage generates the url privatly by default, using I suppose the secret key base. Can you check the secret key base on each of your apps?

Comment: Yes, a small segment is different. How do I check the secret key base? I'm on Heroku

Comment: UPDATE: I updated the secret key base of App2 to match App1's and it worked!